# Let $dp=\mu(t)p(t)dt − k\,p(t)h(t)dt.$ Why $E[dp]=0$?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Assuming for simplicity that the price falls during a crash by a fixed percentage $k \in (0, 1)$, the asset price dynamics is given by
$$dp=\mu(t)p(t)dt − k\,p(t)h(t)dt.$$
In a paper I read: The no-arbitrage condition and rational expectations together imply that $E[dp]=0$. Why?

Comment: what is $\mu(t)$, $h(t)$ and did the paper say which stochastic process this is. also, what paper was it

Comment: Thank you! Eq (6) here: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/1351847X.2011.601657

Comment: It's a martingale process. $\mu(t)$ is drift and $h(t)$ is a hazard rate, both defined in the paper and the model from the following source that also addresses the expectations: Johansen Ledoit Sornette 2000, https://doi.org/10.1142/S0219024900000115